# find a completion of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

X=(0,1), d(x,y)= |x| + |y| for x not equal y, d(x,x)=0.

zero should be included to the space, but not sure with 1 and  with any other points. or should we change the center of the metric from zero to  other points, so we would be able to find convergent points for cauchy sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the only Cauchy sequences are sequences $(x_n)$ such that (why?)
$$
\lim |x_n| = 0
$$
So take $Y = [0,1)$ with this same metric, then $Y$ is complete and contains $X$ as a dense subspace - hence it is, upto isometry, the unique completion of $X$.

Comment: thanks. it's the key point.